# Custom form field type in Symfony

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity with an array field data (doctrine array). I want to create a symfony form for this entity and i would like include this field in it.

So, the question is:
Is there any way to use custom type as form field in Symfony?

This is form field:

```
/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="dates", type="array")
 */
private $dates;
```

This is formType:

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('dates') // i want to use ->add('dates','array') but type 'array' is not allowed
        ;
    }
```

This is data i want to save:

```
$dates = array(
        'birthday' => \DateTime('1995'),
        'wedding' => \DateTime('2001'),
        // and so on
    )
```

Comment: Add some code to illustrate your question: data dumps, form type you have already created, etc...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony assotiative array form field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27830586/symfony-assotiative-array-form-field)

Comment: @Ziumin check please my edits

Comment: Add an example of your data, please. And how should you edit it? Do you want to provide a collection of text field or some advanced datagrid? Or it should be edited as some json_encoded data in a textarea?

Comment: @Ziumin i've edited my question, check please. I suppose the data to come in JSON format via REST API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as there is no built-in data type, you should add your custom one. It'll be enough to extend simple text field (TextType) with a [DataTransformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) which can do array<->json transformation.

Let's assume, your custom type will be `YourBundle\Form\Type\JSONArrayType`. To use it in your form as a regular field you should register in your bundle config:

```
json_array_type.service:
class: YourBundle\Form\Type\JSONArrayType
tags:
  - { name: form.type, alias: json_array_type }
```

And then you can use it in your form type like `$builder->add('dates', 'json_array_type')`

For more information  see [How to Create a Custom Form Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html)